# AWS redis set expire doesn't work properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'm new to AWS Redis. I used expire to set the expiration time as 48h.

```
from datetime import timedelta
r = redis.Redis(host=some aws entrypoint, charset="utf-8", decode_response
s=True)
r.hset("key", "field", "value")
result = r.expire("key", timedelta(minutes=(60 * 48)))
print("expire: " + str(self._r.ttl("key")), file=sys.stderr)
```

The result will return True. And It will print out "172800" as predicted.

However, after about 2 hours, if I don't access to the same key during this period, the ttl will return -2. If I frequently hget the same key, the ttl will work as expected (such as "168849"). It will be very helpful if someone can explain the reason for me. I need the keys to expire only after 48h. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more details? Are you testing an empty redis cache with just this value? Are you using a LRU based policy? More info: https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a new Redis node. The maximum memory is not reached. I guess the LRU policy should not been triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return result of "-2" means the key no longer exists.

So it's either deleted by your code somewhere, or automatically evicted by the Redis.If you are sure your code didn't delete it, just start a fresh redis, do the same thing again,
then in the redis-cli , enter

> info stats

In the output, check the *[evicted_keys](https://redis.io/commands/info)* , it means "Number of evicted keys due to maxmemory limit". So if it's 1, you know it's the maxmemory limit issue.
Then enter

> info memory

Check your used_memory, and maxMemory.

If evicted_keys=0 but expired_keys=1, you know the key is somehow expired.

Then you can use the *[monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor)* command to monitor the Redis server, and do your test again, this time, check what exactly does your redis-client library issue to the Redis server, eg, if the expire time is being set correctly.